# Infinite product limit

Tags: limits

Suppose we have the infinite product $2(1/2)(2^4)(1/2^8)(2^{16})\dots$ I have a hunch that the infinite product is $0$ despite partial product being strictly positive. Am I correct? If so, then how?

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: The part of the sentence "despite partial product being strictly positive" indicates that you are a tad surprised that the infinite product could be equal to zero? That's not so strange, consider $(1/2)(1/2)(1/2)(1/2).....$. All terms are strictly positive but the product has a limit zero. In your example, as indicated by others, the answer turns out to be a non zero value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taking $\log_2$ of the sequence, we get that this limit is just $2$ to the power of

$$1-1+4-8+16$$

which does not converge in the normal sense, so the original product doesn't converge.

Comment: So the limit does not exist?

Comment: @lulu Yes, I just fixed that.

Comment: @user328442 Correct. I just clarified that in my answer.

Comment: The even partial sums go to $-\infty$ and the odd partial sums go to $+\infty$.  So it doesn't converge.  For the product itself: the even partial products go to $0$ and the odd partial products go to $+\infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar that makes perfect sense to me now. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Note that we have: $2 \cdot \frac 12 \cdot 2^4 \cdot \frac{1}{2^8} \cdot... = 2 \cdot 2^{-1} \cdot {2^4} \cdot 2^{-8} \cdot ... = 2^{1-1+4-8+16-...}$

As the sum of the exponents doesn't converge we have that the product doesn't converge too.

Answer (score 1):

For a limit of an infinite product to exist, you need the terms in the product to converge to the multiplicative identity (like with sums, to the additive identity). In your product they do not.

Comment: The terms can also converge to $0$. They don't, of course, but if they did it woul also be OK.

Comment: @5xum I don't see how? What happens if you take the log of the partial products?

Comment: We sometimes say that an infinite product "diverges to zero".  So that could be the content of the question.  In this case it does not diverge to zero.

Comment: I see. I have seen the formulation that a product with terms of the form $1+a_n$ converges iff. the sum $\sum a_n$ converges which it would not if $a_n\rightarrow -1$

Comment: The idea of saying that an infinite product diverges to zero is a consequence of the relationship with sums and the unfortunate convention of using the word "diverge" for limits approaching $-\infty$.

Comment: @qbert That formulation is true if the sequence $a_n$ is not arbitrarily close to $0$. Obviosly, the infinite product $0\cdot 0\cdot 0\cdots$ converges, and in fact the product converges if only *one* of the terms is $0$ (since, then, partial products are all equal to $0$).